# What does the following error mean, when I tried to import torch library on iPython?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

---

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

### RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import torch

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/**init**.py in ()
     51 sys.setdlopenflags(_dl_flags.RTLD_GLOBAL | _dl_flags.RTLD_NOW)
     52 
---> 53 from torch._C import *
     54 
     55 **all** += [name for name in dir(_C)

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update your numpy installation.

Run this in terminal:

`pip install -U numpy`

If this doesn't work, try uninstalling and then reinstalling it:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Why won't pip uninstall jumpy command work?

pip uninstall numpy
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/...

Comment: try this: `sudo pip install --ignore-installed numpy`

Comment: ok, that did update the Numpy to the latest version.  Thanks

but when I import torch, I somehow still get the above error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c031d3dd82fc> in <module>()
----> 1 import torch